# set method on host object

Tags: java, java-11, graalvm

```
public class Thing {
  public Thing() {
  }

  public void run() {
  }

  public void out(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}

Context context = Context.create("js");
Value jsBindings = context.getBindings("js");

jsBindings.putMember("this", new Thing());
context.eval("js", "this.run = () => this.out('hi');");
jsBindings.getMember("this").getMember("run").execute();

context.close();
```

I am expecting the output `hi` but I get no output.

I wonder if the javascript (`context.eval` section) is not updating the host object (`new Thing()`) that I provide it with.

Comment: Are you sure `"this"` is not a reserved variable name like in Java?

Comment: @Robert it's special yeah. How do I set the global `this` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `putMember("this", new Thing())` will *not* modify the global `this`, but put a property named `this` in the global object, accessible via `this.this`.
   And the answer to "how do I set the global this" is, I'm afraid: you can't.
2. Assigning to host (i.e. Java) object methods is not possible. You can however implement a Java interface using a JS object, using [`Value.as(Class)`](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Value.html#as-java.lang.Class-), e.g. you can do the following:

```java
public interface Thing {
  void run();
}
Context context = Context.create("js");
Value jsobj = context.eval("js", "({run: () => console.log('hi')})");
Thing javaobj = jsobj.as(Thing.class);
javaobj.run();
```

Comment: do you know how to do the same with an abstract class instead of an interface ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54451859/3310334